# how to solve the c warning :pointer from integer without a cast?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memcpy

warning :  passing argument 2 of ‘memcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

```
uint8 InterruptLatency;
char buf[256];
int kernelinterrupt time()
{
    fscanf(fp, "%"SCNu8"\n", &InterruptLatency);  // I am reading the data from kernel which is not shown here
  memcpy(buf, InterruptLatency, sizeof(InterruptLatency));   // warning here as above

    // after storing it in buffer I am sending the data from but to another layer
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `memcpy()` function expects two pointers, but `InterruptLatency` is an 8-bit integer.

The solution is to take the address of the variable:

```
memcpy(buf, &InterruptLatency, sizeof InterruptLatency);
            ^
            |
        address-of
        operator
```

Note that no parentheses are needed for `sizeof` when taking the size of an actual object. This is because `sizeof` is not a function.

Also note that using `memcpy()` for copying a single byte into a byte array like this would never happen in "real" C code. I'd just do:

```
buf[0] = InterruptLatency;
```